# Windsor: How do you scope your services pr usercontrol?

Tags: castle-windsor

I am developing a winforms application and I have a scenario where I want to scope the lifetime of some services to the lifetime of a usercontrol (which there can be many of in the application). What is the best way of doing this in Castle Windsor?

One approach I was thinking of was to create a child container in the usercontrol, register all the services which i want to scope, as singletons into the child container and then use the child container to resolve the object graph which will be used internally in the usercontrol. I would really like to keep my ioc configuration in my prism modules instead of having them "scattered" (well not very scattered but you get the point) over the code-base.

Are there any other ways of achieving this? I've read that you can use Handle-selectors and SubResolvers to accomplish context scoping of services, but I haven't found a blog describing how.

Edit:

When I say "usercontrol" I mean pr root usercontrol, child controls of the usercontrol should be scoped by their parent. I've solved it by creating a child container pr root usercontrol and register the scoped services into the child container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is imprecise. What does that mean per-control? What if control has sub-controls? How would you detect the scope you're in?

Implementation-wise you need to implement a custom [lifestyle](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.LifeStyles.ashx).

Comment: I don't see how I can resolve the scope I'm in by using some static context (like you can with web-requests), that's is why I'm opting for child containers. Of course, I am avoiding the service-locator anti pattern so that any dynamic service resolving within the scope is done by factories which have a ctor dependency to the container they should dynamically resolve with. The child container registers itself as an IWindsorContainer service so that factories will get the child container reference.

Comment: The 'how to resolve scope' is not really a Windsor question I would say. You might experiment with custom lifestyle for your control which when resolving does `context.AddContextualProperty("scope", new MyScope())` or something...

Comment: Its not directly Windsor related, but I am guessing that this must be a pretty common problem. I'm just looking for the best practice in such situations.

Comment: Right. In that case you need two things: A per/control cache. A way to access it in your lifetime manager and a way for it to get disposed when you dispose of the control

Comment: Don't know about WinForms, but for example in WPF this can be achieved by making your controls (or more precisely - screens) explicit concepts and using frameworks like Magellan